# Singularity; get a github repo into the users home directory

Tags: git, permissions, virtual-machine, singularity-container

### Aim

The aim is to create a singularity container that installs some packages, then clones a custom package from a git repo and makes it. The user needs to have permission to do things with the custom package, and ideally it would sit in the home directory of the singularity user, but that seems more difficult than I had anticipated.

The singularity will be almost always launched as a shell, it is to contain a group of troublesome custom packages and generate results from them in a repeatable, sharable manner.

### Problem

Cloning the git repo seems fine, but the only place I can put it that the user can even see it is `/github_repo` and it is always owned by root.

I can't get it to the user's home directory because during `%post` the variable `$HOME` does not seem to point to the users home directory, it points to `/root`, and object that are created then belong to root. In fact while `/home` does exist it is empty, it seems like the user doesn't exist yet.

I have tried cloning to `/github_repo` then adding

```
chown -R $USER /github_repo
chmod -R 766 /github_repo
```

to `%post`.
The container can be built and run, and when it is running;

```
$ ls -lh /github_repo
ls: cannot access '/github_repo': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?           ? CorrectNameOfGithubFolder
-????????? ? ? ? ?           ? CorrectNameOfGithubFile
```

So it can see the names of the files and folders, but not their permissions? I didn't even know that was possible. If I don't mess around with permissions in `%post` it is a perfectly normal file owned by root.

### Recipe

This is what I have so far, you should find it builds and runs.
If you want to run it save the recipy as example.def then do

```
sudo singularity build example.sif example.def
singularity run --containall example.sif
```

and then try

```
$ ls -lh /packages
```

#### example.def

```
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:18.04
    
# commands on the host system
%setup
    # make print colour #
    GREEN='\033[0;32m'
    NOCOLOUR='\033[0m'
    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Getting modified packages from github ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    export PACKAGES_TMP=/tmp/packages
    rm -fr $PACKAGES_TMP
    mkdir -p $PACKAGES_TMP
    git clone https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy-tutorials.git $PACKAGES_TMP
    cp -R ${PACKAGES_TMP} ${SINGULARITY_ROOTFS}

# get files from the host (but we dont need any)
%files

# what is done when the container is built
%post
    # make print colour #
    GREEN='\033[0;32m'
    NOCOLOUR='\033[0m'
    # start
    echo "${GREEN}~~~ install apt packages ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    apt -y update
    # for fetching from repos if needed
    apt -y install git
    # for getting anything else from the net
    apt -y install wget
    # text editors
    apt -y install vim-tiny
    apt -y install nano
    # for making downloaded packages
    apt -y install make

    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Set up a .bashrc ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    BASHRC=/home/.bashrc
    touch $BASHRC
    echo "alias vim=vim.tiny\n" >> $BASHRC
    # will be called in run

    ## Not working???
    ## the /home/ directory appears empty
    # echo "${GREEN}~~~ Move packages to home dir ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    MY_HOME=$(ls -l /home/)
    echo in post home is $MY_HOME
    touch ~/test
    touch $HOME/test
    mkdir $HOME/test_dir
    # PACKAGES=$MY_HOME/packages/
    # mv /packages $PACKAGES
    
    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Give the user permission and control ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    # this bit does odd things
    PACKAGES=/packages
    chown -R $USER $PACKAGES
    chmod -R 766 $PACKAGES

    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Making the packages ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    # need to implement


# enviroment variabels instide the container
# sourced at run time not build time
%environment
    export PACKAGES=/packages/
    export BASHRC=/home/.bashrc


# this is executed when the contain is launched with
# singularity run example.sif
%runscript
    MY_HOME=$(ls -l /home/)
    echo at run home is $MY_HOME
    touch ~/runtest1
    touch $HOME/runtest2
    mkdir $HOME/runtest_dir
    ls -lh /
    ls -lh $HOME
    ls -lh $HOME/runtest_dir/
    # source the .bashrc
    echo $BASHRC
    /bin/bash --rcfile $BASHRC
    

# this would be executed just after build
%test
    echo I havent written any tests

# metadata
%labels
    Author ClumsyCat
    Version v1.0

%help
    to build me
    > sudo singularity build example.sif example.def
    to run me do
    > singularity run --containall --bind /my/out/dir/ example.sif
        the "--containall" flag prevents interactions with your system
        the "--bind /my/out/dir/" mounts a directory in your system
        this allows scripts in that directory to be accessed from the image
        and results from the image to persist in the directory
        It also allows the run script to call .bashrc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

1. Unless there's something you *really* need on the host system, [don't use `%setup`](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/definition_files.html#setup). It's running as root on the host OS and it's really easy to break things in ways you don't expect.
2. By default singularity mounts the running user's `$HOME` into the container, so anything you put in `/home/...` is going to be overwritten unless the user uses `--no-home`. [Best practices](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/definition_files.html#best-practices-for-build-recipes) recommend against installing to $HOME for this reason
3. All the steps in `%post` when you're referencing $USER is setting it to root, because that is the user when it is being run (`sudo singularity build ...`), so it's actually doing anything
4. `chmod -R 664` - this is breaking your directories. You need the execute bit in order to actually access the directory, not just read

I've adjusted your sample definition file to work more as you intend. Comments explain why.

```
BootStrap: docker
From: ubuntu:18.04

%post
    # make print colour #
    GREEN='\033[0;32m'
    NOCOLOUR='\033[0m'
    PACKAGES=/packages

    # give all files 774 and directories 775 by default
    umask 002

    # start
    echo "${GREEN}~~~ install apt packages ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    # install everything at once and use apt-get for non-interactive installs
    apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y git wget vim-tiny nano make

    # create a symlink to vim instead of an alias
    ln -s $(which vim.tiny) /usr/local/bin/vim

    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Getting modified packages from github ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    # git clone in %post instead of %setup
    mkdir $PACKAGES
    cd $PACKAGES
    git clone https://github.com/rootpy/rootpy-tutorials.git

    echo "${GREEN}~~~ Making the packages ~~~ ${NOCOLOUR}"
    # need to implement
    echo do something here

%environment
    export PACKAGES=/packages

%runscript
    echo I am $(whoami)
    echo

    cd $PACKAGES
    echo I am in $PWD
    ls -la --color=auto
    echo

    echo vim is: $(which vim)
```

Running `singularity run --containall example.sif` gives:

```
I am tsnowlan

I am in /packages
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 3 root     root      39 May 28 12:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 tsnowlan tsnowlan  60 May 28 12:24 ..
drwxrwxr-x 6 root     root     117 May 28 12:23 rootpy-tutorials

vim is: /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks you! Your points are very well explained. I would just add that in order for the user to actually work with the downloaded package (create files and alter files) seems to require `umask 000`

Comment: This is true, but only if the host kernel has Overlay enabled. That is probably the case for most people running on their personal computers, but overlay has some stability issues and is often disabled on large servers (e.g., in HPC environments).

It's useful to always treat the container as read-only and mount in any directories where you can write to your heart's content. That may not be helpful to what you're doing though, and if you know it will only be run with overlay-supported kernels it's probably fine.